# how to change background color of an element shortly on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an element that i would like to change the background color (eg: to blue) on click and back to white (#FFF) instantly. I am not trying to toggle here.

```
('form').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).addClass("blue-bkground").animate({backgroundColor:'#FFF'}, 300).removeClass("blue-bkground"); 
}
```

The above code works once i.e. i can see the effect once, but doesn't work again on subsequent clicks.

Comment: You should retitle the question because your issue is that the event is only firing once, not that you can't change the background color. I can't tell off the bat what's wrong, but trying adding a `e.preventDefault()' in the callback. It could be some weird form element behavior.

Comment: Also why use (this) instead of e.currentTarget ?

Comment: @rsahai i do have e.preventDefault() at the beginning.

Comment: You said above code works once!! can you create the demo in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove class after animation completes, so put it in complete function of animate.

```js
$('form').on('click', 'div', function (e) {            
            $(this).addClass("blue-bkground").animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFF' }, 300, function () { $(this).removeClass("blue-bkground"); });            
        });
```

```css
.blue-bkground
{
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div>Click here</div>
</form>
```

Comment: sure.. glad to help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS.

I've created [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pomLsa40/2/).

```
.bar{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.bar:active{
     background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.